# How to install MySQL 5.6.3 (beta) on Ubuntu?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

has anyone managed to install MySQL 5.6.3 (beta) on Ubuntu? I tried running alien against the server rpm but encountered the following error:

error in Version string '5.6.3_m6-2': invalid character in version number

Thanks
Jason

Comment: I've just realized that although the .tar consisted of the various .rpms, the .tar.gz contains directories/files meant for systems that don't/can't process rpms.

Answer (score 1):

if you are still looking for a solution then you could also try using the instructions at http://www.geeksww.com/tutorials/database_management_systems/mysql/installation/download_configure_compile_and_install_mysql_56.php

this is for the latest available production-ready release ie. 5.6.10 but should also work with previous versions.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: http://www.denoq.com/2012/02/mysql-5-6-4-on-ubuntu-11-10/

I've not tried that but it appears reasonable to your problem: first install an older version, than change only the necessary.